# calculate count in a loop failed 

Tags: shell

Here is my simplified code. **ls** is simplified of **find** command.  **wc** is simplified for another command.

```
n=0
ls *.cpp | while read filename ; do
  c=`wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}'}`
  n=`expr $n + $c`
done
echo "$n"  #always be 0
```

In previous code failed, the following success

```
n=0
ls *.cpp > /tmp/list
while read filename ; do
  c=`wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}'}`
  n=`expr $n + $c`
done < /tmp/list
echo "$n"
```

How to use first form and get correct answer?
Or, how to use 2nd form but without another /tmp/list file?

Maybe my problem is how to pass variable between subshell which is generated automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pipe, [every process except the first one is in a subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done), so the values of `$c` and `$n` are lost. If you want to keep the count, you should put the `while` loop first:

```
while read ...; do
    c=...
    n=...
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cpp')
echo "$n"
```

But there's a better way:

```
wc -l *.cpp | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: +1. If we're golfing, this is fewer processes: `wc -l < <(cat *.cpp)`

Comment: It wasn't meant as golfing, but `cat *.cpp | wc -l` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the following one-liner:

```
wc -l *.cpp | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

However, if you prefer to fix your original script, you could use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
for filename in *.cpp; do
  c=`wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}'`
  n=`expr $n + $c`
done
echo "$n"
```

Comment: The code is used for explain syntax. My origin script's purpose is not used for calculate word count.

Comment: @DanielYCLin Using the output of `ls` is a bad practice because that will fail, for example, if your file names have whitespaces in between (or whatever separator you're using in `IFS`). The best way to iterate through files is to use a `for` loop as in the example above.